# Using the Grid Splidejs extension with Angular 14

Tags: angular, splidejs

I am trying to use the SplideJS Grid extension to create a slider with a grid format and when I install it and import it into my angular project, it gives me an error and stops compiling.

The error is the following:

> Error: node_modules/@splidejs/splide-extension-grid/dist/types/extensions/Grid/Grid.d.ts:11:9 - error TS2411: Property 'Grid' of type 'GridComponent | undefined' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'BaseComponent'.

I edited the "Grid.d.ts" file and on line 11 add a //ts-ignore

```
  interface Components {
      //ts-ignore
        Grid?: GridComponent;
    }
}
```

and it let me run angular and the library works when the page loads, but when I navigate to any route using [routerLink] the slider disappears until the page is reloaded.

This is the code where I implement it

```js
    import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChildren, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import {Splide} from '@splidejs/splide';
    import { Grid } from '@splidejs/splide-extension-grid';
    import { Publications_Meta } from 'src/app/shared/interfaces/publication-meta.interface';
    import { Publications } from 'src/app/shared/interfaces/publications.interface';
    import { PublicationsService } from 'src/app/shared/services/publications.service';
        
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-publication',
          templateUrl: './publication.component.html'
        })
        
        export class PublicationComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
         publication! : Publications;
         publication_meta! : Publications_Meta;
         @ViewChild('gallery', {read: ElementRef})  gallery!: ElementRef;
         @ViewChildren("galleryitems") galleryitems: any;
        
        
         constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, public publicationsService : PublicationsService) {
        
         }
        
        
         PublicationsSlider() {
          const slider : Splide = new Splide( this.gallery.nativeElement, {
            perPage: 2,
            pagination: false,
            arrows: false,
            grid: {
            dimensions: [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2 ] ],
            gap : {
            row: '1rem',
            col: '1.5rem' },
            },  
            breakpoints: {
              600: {
                perPage: 1,
                grid: false,
                gap: '1rem',
              },
            },
          } )
          return slider;
        }
        
        
        ngOnInit(): void {
        
          this.route.params
                .subscribe( params=> {
                  this.publicationsService.getByID(params['id'])
                        .subscribe( (publication) => {
                          this.publication = publication as Publications;
                        });
        
                  this.publicationsService.getMeta(params['id'])
                        .subscribe( (publication_meta) => {
                          this.publication_meta = publication_meta as Publications_Meta;
                        });
                });
        
        
         }
        
        
        ngAfterViewInit(): void {
          this.galleryitems.changes.subscribe(() => {
            this.PublicationsSlider().mount();
            });
          }
        }



 HTML:

    <div id="gallery" class="pub-gallery splide" #gallery>
                  <div class="splide__track">
                        <ul class="splide__list">
                          <li #galleryitems class="splide__slide" *ngFor="let image of publication_meta.gallery; let i = index;">
                            <img [src]="image" [alt]="publication.titulo+i">
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: There is missing code where you implement the class

Comment: I added the code where I implement the slider

Comment: But nowhere you are using the interface Components.

Comment: The error is thrown when @splidejs/splide-extension-grid is installed via npm and imported into angular, at the time of executing the command to build the exception that I wrote at the beginning appears. So that it no longer appears, I edited directly on the grid.d.ts file that belongs to the splidejs extension so that typescript would ignore the error and allow me to compile. After that it works, but then the slider disappears when I navigate between routes using [routerLink].

Answer (score 0):

use | async pipe in your template (HTML) so your slider will be rendered after you've gotten the data. I think that right now it's trying to show it without having the data, so it is never initialized properly.

Or perhaps, mount the publicationsslider after data is received AND the view is initialized. Instead of in the NgAfterViewInit.

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

The benefit of using the async pipe in your template instead of in your ts file, is that it automatically unsubscribes from your observable as well when your component is destructed.

I've had a little similar issue myself, with ChartJS (you need to mount the chart manually, just like you have to do with your slider).
Can't provide an example code now since I am short on time, good luck.

Comment: I assigned a pipe async as you indicate and the same behavior continues, when you refresh the browser or open the url directly it works fine, then if you navigate using angular routing to another page that has the same slider it appears empty.

Comment: I needed to say that I have several @Splidejs sliders in this same application and they all work when navigating within the page using routerlink but these sliders do not have the Grid extension implemented, only this one that has said extension is the one that does not work.